# Rails -- CSS import rule

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have an @import rule within a CSS file in my asset path:

```
// /app/assets/product/ow.css.scss
@import 'foo.css.scss';
```

And I put foo.css.scss inside the same folder.  Rails is automatically pulling in foo.css since it's in the asset path, and then it's duplicating the request to pull in foo.css because of the import.

What's the correct way to handle CSS @import rules within the Rails framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` and remove Sprockets directives. My guess is `*= require_tree .` is causing your `@import` to be pulled twice. Check out the [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) documentation for more information.